# Question of explictly defining an isomorphism.

Tags: order-theory, model-theory

Let $(\mathbb{Q},0,1,<)$ be the rational numbers, considered as structures in the language $\mathcal{L}=\{0,1,<\}$.

Question is that:

Explicitly define an isomorphism $i:(\mathbb{Q},0,1,<) \rightarrow (\mathbb{Q},0,1,<)$ other than the identity map $i(q)=q$.

My Answers are $i(q) = q + 1$ or $i(q) = q + q$ or $i(q) = q \cdot q$.

Are these answers okay for this question ?

Also, I want to ask does the first-order Language include the function symbol $+$ and the function symbol $\cdot$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of these work. The isomorphism needs to take $0\mapsto 0$ and $1\mapsto 1,$ so that rules out the first two. It also needs to preserve order, which rules out the third. Instead, think about an order preserving map that fixes $0$ and $1.$ For instance, anything of the form $ax+b$ where $a,b\in \mathbb Q$ and $a>0$ is an order preserving map $\mathbb Q\to \mathbb Q$ (i.e. an isomorphism of $(\mathbb Q,< )).$ It will take some thinking to figure out how to use this idea to get something that also fixes $0$ and $1,$ since the only linear function that will preserve $0$ and $1$ is $a=1,b=0,$ which is just the identity... you need to play around with related ideas.

The language you have written down doesn't include $+$ or $\cdot$... they would be written down there if they were included. This just means our ismorphism doesn't need to preserve these functions. There is nothing wrong with using these functions to define our isomorphism, which is something we do in the metatheory, not the language itself.

---

**edit**

Here is an explicit isomorphism: Let $$i(q) = \begin{cases} q& q<1\\2q-1&q\ge 1\end{cases}.$$ It's easy to verify the $i$ is a bijction $\mathbb Q\to \mathbb Q$ with $i(0)=0,$ $i(1)=1,$ and $i(x)<i(y)\iff x<y,$ which is what it means to be an isomorphism.

You had a good idea of trying $i(q)=q^3,$ which has $i(0)=0,$ $i(1)=1,$ and $i(x)<i(y)\iff x<y,$ however, it is not an isomorphism since it is not a bijection. Its image only consists of rationals that are perfect cubes, not all of the rationals, so it is not surjective. It would definitely be a nontrivial isomorphism if the structure were $(\mathbb R,0,1,<)$ rather than $(\mathbb Q,0,1,<).$

Comment: Question: is the first actually okay if you realize 1 as 2 and 0 as 1 in the new structure? It seems to me 0 and 1 have no special properties in this particular language.

Comment: @NicholasViggiano There is no new structure... both structures are the same one with $0$ and $1$ the numbers we know and love.  It would make sense (but be slightly strange) to ask for an isomorphism between $(\mathbb Q, 0,1, <)$ and $(\mathbb Q, 2,1,>)$ which would need to be a bijection $\mathbb Q\to \mathbb Q$ that takes $0\mapsto 2,$ $1\mapsto 1$ and is order-reversing. In other words, the same constant symbol could be interpreted as two different numbers in the two different structures with the same domain and the relation symbol could be interpreted as something different as well.

Comment: @NicholasViggiano For instance, a more natural example (with not quite the same domain) would that the exponential function $e^x$ is an isomorphism between $(\mathbb R,+,0)$ and $(\mathbb R^+,\cdot, 1).$

Comment: @NicholasViggiano It might seem a little odd take two elements that have no special role in the ordering, and single them out by adding them to the language and demanding embeddings and isomorphisms preserve them (usually in ordinary mathematical practice we would name a constant as part of the structure because it is special somehow)... but that's what's being done if the structure is $(\mathbb Q,0,1,<).$ If the structure were just $(\mathbb Q,<),$ then sure, the first (and the second) would be isomorphisms.

Comment: Then, how about $i(q) = q \cdot q \cdot q$ is this working ? Let $\mathfrak{A} = (\mathbb{Q}, 0, 1, <)$ and $\mathfrak{B} = (\mathbb{Q}, 0, 1, <)$, then $i(0^\mathfrak{A})$ = $0^\mathfrak{B}$ and $i(1^\mathfrak{A})$ = $1^\mathfrak{B}$, also it holds < for both positive and negative of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @xxxxxx I don't see why you don't just write it $i(q)=q^3.$ Per the last paragraph in my answer, this is just an ordinary mathematical function... we aren't hamstrung by needing to express it in any particular restrictive language. It actually doesn't work though, although it's more subtle... even though it fixes everything it needs to and preserves order, it is not a bijection.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Sorry, I am quite lost here. Well then how I suppose to define an isomorphism $i$ other than $i(q) = q$ or you mean that $i$ isn't definable if the language $\mathcal{L}$ and the structure does not has any funtion symbol like $\cdot$ and $^3$ etc.

Comment: @xxxxxx What I was going for was something piecewise linear. Like $i(q)=q$ for $q\le 1$ and $i(q)=2q-1$ for $q>1.$ This is a bijection that preserves order and $0$ and $1.$

Comment: @xxxxxx I added the full solution, as well as an explanation of why $i(q)=q^3$ doesn't quite work into the answer.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Okay, I think I know why. And just make sure is that $i(q) = q$ for $q \leq 1$ $i(q) = \frac{1}{2} q + \frac{1}{2}$ for $q > 1$ also works right ? Just make sure that $i(q) = q$ when $q = 0$ or $q = 1$ right and the other part be linear

Comment: @xxxxxx yes, that also works

Comment: @spacedarkgreen I understand how constants work, just misunderstood the notation (forgetting that the structure notation is already the realization and is no longer just the symbols). Cheers!